Nx add global target in nx.json
I create a plugin called check-types (@project/nx/plugins/check-types": ["plugins/check-types/src/index.ts"]) with an executor called run.
Now if I update the project.json of a project, I can run my plugin without problems:
"targets": {
    "check-types": {
      "executor": "@project/nx/plugins/check-types:run"
    }
  }

However, I would like to configure something at nx.json level that, when I call for check-types, it calls the plugin executor on the project directly.
Also if possible, with the option to target ts based project, otherwise I handle this part in the plugin.

After researching for quite some time I found that it is indeed possible to add global targets, not from the nx.json, but by exporting a const called createNodesV2 from the index file of your plugin.
It is important to register the plugin in nx.json for this to work.
Notice that there is an older version called createNodes that still works but is being migrated. So in future updates this const might be called again createNodes.
export const createNodesV2: CreateNodesV2 = [
  '**/project.json',
  (projectConfigurationFiles, _, __): CreateNodesResultV2 =>
    projectConfigurationFiles.map((file): [string, CreateNodesResult] => {
      const normalizedPath = normalizePath(file);
      const jsonConfig = readJsonFile(file);
      const projectRoot = normalizedPath.replace('/project.json', '');
      return [
        file,
        {
          projects: {
            [projectRoot]: {
              ...jsonConfig,
              targets: {
                ...jsonConfig.targets,
                'check-types': {
                  executor: '@project/nx/plugins/check-types:run',
                  options: {
                    cwd: normalizedPath,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ];
    }),
];

